# count in sub-query in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am new bee of Zf2, so please suggest how should I create following sql in Zend framework 2?

Select mt1.*, 
(select count(mt2.parent_id)
 from md_type as mt2 
 where mt2.parent_id = mt1.id)) as cnt
from md_type as mt1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$sub = new Select('md_type');
$sub->columns(array(new Expression('COUNT(mt2.parent_id) as total')))
    ->where(array(
        new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('mt2.parent_id = mt1.id')
    ))
;

$subquery = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("({$sub->getSqlString()})");

$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select('mt1');
$select->columns(array('*', 'cnt' => $subquery));
```

this would produce:

```
SELECT mt1.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(mt2.parent_id) as total 
     FROM "md_type" 
     WHERE mt2.parent_id = mt1.id
    ) AS cnt 
FROM mt1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$sql = new Sql($this->_adapter);
$mainSelect = $sql->select()->from('mt1');
$subQry = $sql->select()
        ->from('md_type')
        ->columns(array('orderCount' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(md_type.parent_id)')))
        ->where('mt2.parent_id = mt1.id');
$mainSelect->columns(
        array(
            'id', 
            'total' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('?', array($subQry)),
        )
);

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($mainSelect);
$comments = $statement->execute();
$resultSet = new ResultSet();
$resultSet->initialize($comments);

return $resultSet->toArray();
```

Reference: [ZF2 - subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742290/subquery-in-zend-framework2/15743270#15743270)